# Using or creating Wi-Fi Direct (P2P) connection on ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, wifi, espressif, softap

I want to make a Wi-Fi Direct connection with an android device using my ESP8266. According to [ESP8266WiFi Documentation](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.4_a/) and [ESP8266 datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf), the board has a SoftAP mode which is I think what is needed in a P2P connection (Being an AP and a client at the same time).

There is also ESP-NOW in the Espressif website but I think it's made only for esp-to-esp p2p connection and I can't modify it. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

I couldn't find any pre-made libraries for this job, so I decided to make my own, but I can't seem to find anything related to making a new type of protocol or connection. Is it even possible to develop a new type of protocol? If yes, I'd really appreciate a guide on how to get started.

Comment: why not use esp8266 arduino? https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino#installing-with-boards-manager

Comment: @Juraj I'm sorry, but I looked into the [Documentation mentioned in that repository](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.4_a/) but I couldn't find anything related to Wi-Fi Direct or P2P. Also when I mentioned "ESP8266WiFi documentation" I meant the library that you just shared. Can you please clarify which part of the library or documentation explains it?

Comment: the WiFi library of the "esp8266 Arduino boards support package" handles SoftAP and WiFi STA. AP and STA can be used together. you can receive and send data on both interfaces. btw; I wonder why you call the "esp8266 Arduino  boards support package" "documentation". the docs are here https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Maybe explain a little more what you want to achieve and why you need the esp to be both AP and station. I think you confuse some things, a client is usually sth on a different layer (you have websocket/http/... clients).

Comment: @SimSon As I explained, I need to establish a P2P connection (More specifically, use Wi-Fi Direct). A Wi-Fi direct connection requires both devices to be an AP & client at the same time (So they don't need to have the same access point to connect to) as explained [here](http://www.it.uc3m.es/~pablo/papers/pdf/2012_camps_commag_wifidirect.pdf)

Comment: @Juraj Yes, it does handle SoftAP and I can use it, but it's not obvious (or even possible) to make P2P connections with just that. You need more than just being an access point and connecting to an access point; To be able to make a P2P connection. Since ESP supports 802.11, It has the hardware capabilities for it. But I'm stuck at finding the right code/library to do it. Also, the exact link that you mentioned as "The docs are here" is the link in my comment.

Comment: what should that library do? P2P or WiFi direct is a connection without separate WiFi AP. if one of the esp starts the SoftAP and the other connects to it as STA, it is P2P.

Comment: i read it
can you do it in the end?